# How to detect payment's fraud using Machine Learning?

Tags: classification, supervised-learning

While browsing Machine Learning problems, I came across this question:

"Given a month’s worth of login data from Netflix such as account_id, device_id, and metadata concerning payments, how would you detect payment fraud?"

Now, I would approach this problem as a supervised learning exercise    and leverage past data as training data where hopefully, a response was provided for each sample and determined to be fraudulent or not.

- I would train a classification model on this training data with the
  objective of minimizing the False Positives (Type I error), i.e. after obtaining a model, I
  would set the probability threshold to be low so as to minimize the
  False Negatives.
- I am thinking that most of these problems are usually highly
  imbalanced (with very few cases of fraud), and so, I would probably
  not use accuracy as a performance metric to evaluate the performance
  of the model (and use precision instead, or perhaps precision-recall AUC).

Now I am wondering if my approach is correct, is there anything missing from my Logic?
In the past I have solved similar 'fraud' problems, however, the question were regarding credit card transactions, and the challenge was to detect whether a particular transaction was fraudulent or not.

And so, for this particular Netflix problem, I am not sure if the fact that, here, the challenge is to detect whether payments are fraudulent (instead of transactions) makes any difference or not.

I am curious to hear what other people think.